# Apply arbitrary geometric transforms to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I have some Swing controls in a JPanel.  I want this panel to appear on the screen transformed by some arbitrary affine transformation, and for all the controls to remain interactive.  Lets assume a rotation by 20 degrees and a scale down to 75% normal size for example.

The closest I have seen for how to do this is here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/343261/GUI/java/Applying-affine-transform-JPanel
(but unfortunately this solution does not result in the controls being interactive)

Also there is this post:
http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.gui/2004-02/0719.html
(for which there did not seem to be a neat solution, but perhaps now (6 years on) things have changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JXLayer for that. More info is at http://www.pbjar.org/blogs/jxlayer/jxlayer40/